# Php - Creating a Basic Point of Sales Web Application

Tags: php, laravel, point-of-sale

I’m currently practicing php and wanting to create a simple POS web app with an inventory system. However, I do not know exactly the logic on how to handle the POS page itself (see example screenshot below). When I click an item, how should I be able to get the product and post it to the database? Should I store it in sessions or what? Can someone have just even a high level explanation to me? I tried finding a tutorial on how to create a dynamic POS but I haven’t seen one. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: personally i dont think this is a great practice project. no one would write a POS system in php (ok some one would, but its far from an ideal language for it)

Answer (score 2):

> When I click an item, how should I be able to get the product and post it to the database?

In a traditional web application, this is handled via URLs and query parameters.  When you generate the HTML to create a button, form, etc, the URL it posts to includes the database ID of the *thing* (in this case the product) that you want to operate on.  In more modern applications where actions are triggered by javascript that post URLs, the ID is often encoded in an data attribute.  Something like this.

```
<a href="/foo.php?product_id=27" class="btn">...</a>
<a href="/foo/product/27" class="btn">...</a>
<a href="/foo" data-id="27">...</a>

<form method="POST" action="/foo">
    <button>Product Name</button>
    <input type="hidden" value="27" name="product_id">
</form>
```

As [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) points out in the comments below, using actual links (as in the examples above) can have a lot of negative consequences for something that's going to exist on the public internet.  Typically, if you're making a request that's going to change data you'll do so with `POST` request via a `<form>` or javascript.

Comment: Hello, in the POS page itself, should I be storing the clicked items in the session before I check out? Also, what should be the approach if I try to remove the clicked item in the POS page?

Comment: yes, usually you would store "Cart" like data in the visitors/customers session.

Comment: Don't use links! Links make GET requests! GET requests are supposed to be **safe**. This will end up causing problems like "Chrome has noticed you frequently visit the Add Beer To Cart page and has put it on its homepage … and gets regular updates automatically to store in the cache". Use a POST request. Create it using a `<form>`.

Comment: @nimmneun hi, can you explain how these items will be set when I click an item and also be unset when I try to remove them?

Comment: Thanks @Quentin -- links made the most sense to get the "URL with parameters" idea across but you're absolutely right, GET requests for something that would change data is bad news.

Comment: @coderszx That feels like a lot of information to convey in a Stack Overflow question -- you might want to seek out a Laravel or Symfony tutorial.  These frameworks are built for creating the sort of application you're describing.